# what is a DT_VARIANT tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The constructor of `tf.data.Dataset` takes an argument `variant_tensor`, which is only [documented as](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset):

> A DT_VARIANT tensor that represents the dataset.

and

> in the DatasetV2, we expect subclasses to create a variant_tensor and pass it in to the super() call.

Where can I learn what a "DT_VARIANT tensor" or a "variant_tensor" is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Variant Tensor can be a Tensor of any data type.

Some examples of Variant Tensor are shown below:

```py
# Integer element
a = 1
# Float element
b = 2.0
# Tuple element with 2 components
c = (1, 2)
# Dict element with 3 components
d = {"a": (2, 2), "b": 3}
# Element containing a dataset
e = tf.data.Dataset.from_element(10)
```

Explanation about `Variant Tensor` or `DT_Variant` is shown below.

```cpp
// This is an implementation of a type-erased container that can store an
// object of any type. The implementation is very similar to std::any, but has
// restrictions on the types of objects that can be stored, and eschews some of
// the fancier constructors available for std::any. An object of
// tensorflow::Variant is intended to be used as the value that will be stored
// in a tensorflow::Tensor object when its type is DT_VARIANT.
//
// tensorflow::Variant can store an object of a class that satisfies the
// following constraints:
//
// * The class is CopyConstructible.
// * The class has a default constructor.
// * It's either a protocol buffer, a tensorflow::Tensor, or defines the
// following functions:
//
//   string TypeName() const;
//   void Encode(VariantTensorData* data) const;
//   bool Decode(VariantTensorData data);
```

For more details, please refer [TF Org Page](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#__init__) and [Github source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/variant.h).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  While this may answer the literal question, it does not really address the context: what should I pass as the argument to the (Python!) `tf.data.Dataset` constructor?  Could you add some information (or a link to information) about this?

Comment: Edited the Answer and Included TF Org Page and the Example Code for `Variant Tensor`. Please let me know if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: Great, the examples help.  The last missing bit would be an explanation of what to actually pass to the constructor.  What does "represents the dataset" mean?  Is this an example element which can be used to infer the structure of the data?  Or a description of the dataset in some standardised form?  Sorry about being so slow to get this.

Comment: @jochen This answer is not even wrong. None of these are tensors, except `e` which is _kinda._ They are, of course, pure Python values. `tf.data.Dataset` is tensor-like, but it's also a trackable resource, somewhat like the `tf.Variable`, only immutable. There are lots of pitfalls with Python values. Read https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function, https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_graphs and https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function. Consider https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/experimental/StructuredTensor and https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extension_type.